# router.use() requires middleware function error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning node.js, after following this tutorial online, I decided to practice with it. I'm trying to set up the server but getting an error message:

```
 throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.use (/Users/user/Desktop/Movie_Review_API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
```

I think there is something wrong with the routes, but I am not sure what. Here's what I have

Middleware:

```
import { Router } from "express";

export default({config, db}) => {
  let api = Router();

  return api;
}
```

Routes:

```
import express from "express";
import config from "../config"; 
import initializeDb from "../db";
import middleware from "../middleware";
import movie from "../controller/movie";

let router = express();

// connect to db
initializeDb(db => {
router.use(middleware({ config, db }));

  // api routes
  router.use("/movie", movie({config, db}));
});

export default router;
```

server

```
 import http from "http";
    import express from "express";
    import bodyParser from "body-parser";
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
    import config from "./config";
    import routes from "./routes";

    let app = express();
    app.server = http.createServer(app);

    // middleware
    app.use(bodyParser.json({
      limit : config.bodyLimit
    }));

    // passport config

    // api routes v1
    app.use('/v1', routes);

    app.server.listen(config.port);

    console.log(`Started on port ${app.server.address().port}`);

    export default app;
```

controller

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Router } from "express";
import movie from "../model/movie";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

export default({config, db}) => {
  let api = Router();

  api.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    let newMovie = new Movie();
    newMovie.name = req.body.name;
    newMovie.rating = req.body.rating;
    newMovie.releaseYear = req.body.releaseYear;
    newMovie.description = req.body.description;

    newMovie.save(err => {
      if(err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({message: "Movie saved successfully"});
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

not enough rep, but i suggest checking this:

```
app.server.listen(config.port);
//can just be 
app.listen(config.port);
```

and yeah the usual, just check routes, hope that works